# Some random characters are showing up while inserting with Tiny Editor

Tags: php

I am using Tiny Editor to save product description. But when i press enter to give space between paragraphs a random character "rn" begin to show in front end, while displaying the product description. Database Collation is set to utf_general_ci and in header i am also using

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Product description datatype is set to Text and also tried with varchar. But nothing is solving the "rn" character issue.

Here is how i calling the product description in front end

```
<?php 
$SellerMenu = mysqli_query($con, "Select * from food LEFT JOIN categories ON categories.id = food.category Where food.merchant_id = '$merchantId' GROUP BY categories.cat_name");
                    
$categories = [];
                    
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($SellerMenu))
                    {
                        $categories[$row["category"]] = [
                            "name"  => $row["cat_name"],
                            "items" => []
                        ];
                    }
                    
                    $result = mysqli_query($con, "Select * from food Where merchant_id = '$merchantId'");
                    
                    while ($item = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                    {
                        $foodId           = $item["food_id"];
                        $item["quantity"] = 1;
                        
                        // Extract the diets
                        $item["diets"] = [];
                        $dietIds       = explode(",", $item['diet_id']);
                        
                        foreach ($dietIds as $dietId)
                        {
                            $dietResult = mysqli_query($con, "Select * from diets Where id = $dietId");
                                
                            while ($dietRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dietResult))
                            {
                                $item["diets"][] = $dietRow;
                            }
                        }
                        
                        // Extract varieties
                        
                        $item["varietyDetails"] = [];
                        $varietyResult          = mysqli_query($con, "select * from food_variety where food_id = '$foodId'");
                        
                        while ($varietyRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($varietyResult))
                        {
                            $item["varietyDetails"][] = $varietyRow;
                        }
                        
                        // Extract Extras
                        
                        $item["extraDetails"] = [];
                        $extraResult          = mysqli_query($con, "Select * from food_extras Where food_id = '$foodId'");
                        
                        while ($extraRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($extraResult))
                        {
                            $item["extraDetails"][] = $extraRow;
                        }
                        
                        $categories[$item["category"]]["items"][] = $item;
                    }
                    
?>
```

Then

```
 <p v-html="item.description"></p>
```

Comment: `rn` looks like `\r\n` (return + newline) with stripped slashes.

Comment: yes but to get rid of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get rid of that by this

```
<script>

    window.onload = function()
    {
        var str = '<?php echo json_encode($categories);?>'
        
       var categories=str.replace(/\n/g, "\\n").replace(/\r/g, "\\r").replace(/\t/g, "\\t");
       
         categories = JSON.parse(categories);
        window.merchantDetailsVueApp = new Vue({
            el   : "#vueApp",
            data : function()
```